# How to login Windows with LDAP account by using ADFS

Tags: ldap, adfs, windows-server-2016

I have an OpenLDAP server in company for user authentication.

We also have ADFS 2016 installed, and Configured AD FS to authenticate users stored in LDAP directories.

I can login webpage with both LDAP account and AD account, it works well.

But recently, we need to let user sign in windows system with LDAP account (just like Domain User does).

**Problem:**

What should I config on ADFS to enable user sign in Windows System with LDAP account.

If ADFS do not support that, is there any other method can we use to resolve that problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS 4.0 can authenticate users in any LDAP that is v3.0 compliant.

You add the [LDAP as a CP to ADFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-to-authenticate-users-stored-in-ldap-directories).

However, only forms-based authentication is supported for authenticating users from LDAP directories. Certificate-based and Integrated Windows authentication are not supported for authenticating users in LDAP directories.

Comment: Thank you nzpcmad, I searched on the Internet, found that there is a Generic LDAP Connector in "Microsoft Identity Manager 2016",do you know if that support Certificate-based and Integrated Windows authentication?

Comment: That's MIM. MIM is like Biztalk for identity so I don't know if that will work for ADFS. Sorry, know nothing about MIM.

Comment: Thank you all the same nzpcmad, I tried Samba4 act as AD DC,but unfortunately that does not support LDAP as backend either, I will search and try other methods.